Cherenkov radiation in the frame of a moving observer
Imagine a medium in which an electron is moving at speeds faster than the speed of light in the medium. Within the same medium an observer moves at the same speed with the electron. Will the observer detect Cherenkov radiation from the electron in his frame? I think the answer is no because the electron is at rest with respect to the observer. However, the electron is still moving with respect to the medium (or rather the medium is rushing past the electron/observer in their frames) so there must be Cherenkov radiation even in the frame of the observer. I am unable to make up my mind regarding this. Can someone suggest a resolution?
Additional query: What if the electron was at rest and the observer moved faster than the speed of light in the medium? Would the observer detect Cherenkov radiation from the electron in his frame?

There is only one reality. Different frames of reference are just different coordinate systems that measure that reality. That is, if an event (like an electron emitting light) happens in one inertial frame, it happens in all inertial frames. The frames may differ as to the location and time of the event (they give it different coordinates), or even as to the cause of the event (the electron moved through the medium, or the medium moved past the electron) but they all have to agree that the event occured.
So if an electron emits Cherenkov radiation in one inertial frame, it does so in all inertial frames. The frequency of the radiation, or its direction, may be a matter of dispute, but not the existence of the radiation.

Your argument holds in different inertial frames, but not in non-inertial frames. I would recommend specifying for correctness

But I have a suspicion that Cheronkov radiation is not a relativistic effect because the metric in the medium in not a Mikowaski metric so the Lorentz symmetry is not a symmetry of that medium. Therefore, Cheronkov radiation may not be a Lorentz invariant reality. So your assertion may not be correct.

I'm not invoking Lorentz symmetry here, just the existence of an objective reality. Cherenkov radiation is an objective fact, it can be recorded by a camera. If you have a photodetector pointed at the medium, all observers must agree on whether the photodetector records a pulse or not. If you hook that photodetector up to a bomb, all observers must agree on whether the laboratory was blown up or not. If the observer is accelerating, then per @Dale they might not ever know the outcome (an event horizon could form to prevent this) but certainly all inertial observers will agree on the reality.

@EricSmith yes, in general, all observers will agree if a detector goes off, but non-inertial observers may not agree about if it goes off due to radiation or due to rapidly passing through variations of a stationary field. Radiation states can differ between inertial and non-inertial frames.  See here for the most famous example https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unruh_effect

@EricSmith Suppose there is a bomb that is rigged to explode at the detection of a sonic boom from a hypersonic craft. From the frame of the craft, as there was no sonic boom heard the bomb mustn't detonate. But from the frame of the bomb there is a sonic boom and hence, it must detonate. What happens to objective reality here?

In relativity "the frame of the craft" simply means "a system of coordinates where the craft is at rest". It doesn't mean "the inside of the craft "...

... For the example you gave whether or not the bomb goes off depends objectively on the position and relative velocity of the detector and the hypersonic plane. All observers will agree on the reality.  If the detector is inside the plane it will not go off,  and an observer on the ground will agree about this, even if they hear the sonic boom.

@EricSmith My question is about the investigative analysis. What reasoning will the people in the frame of the craft will give to explain the bomb going off? If they posit the sonic boom by what means will they prove the existence of the sonic boom from their frame of reference?

If they tow a microphone behind themselves (offset by an appropriate angle) they could hear the sonic boom through that. They could also observe the sonic booms of other aircraft (see for example https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/17243/does-a-mach-1-plane-hear-a-sonic-boom-from-a-mach-3-plane-overtaking-him).

@Dale Are you referring to things like the Unruh effect? In any practical frame of reference, inertial or not, there is radiation.

@Accumulation yes, but the argument here only holds in inertial frames. Practical or not, Unruh radiation contradicts the argument in non-inertial frames. The argument is correct in inertial frames.

@Dr.user44690 unless the medium is in a place where tidal gravity is significant, the metric is Minkowski.

So you have an electron moving at $\beta =\frac v c > \frac 1 n$, which emits light into a cone with angle:
$$ \cos\theta = \frac 1 {n\beta} $$
I can describe the 4-velocity of a photon in the lab ($S$) as:
$$ q_{\mu} = (\gamma c, \gamma v \sin\theta, 0, \gamma v \cos\theta) $$
which cab be transformed into the electron frame ($S'$, with $c=1$):
$$q'_0 = \gamma^2(1-\frac {\beta} n)$$
with longitudinal component:
$$q'_3 = \gamma^2 (\frac 1 n - \beta) 
$$
and transverse component:
$$ q'_1 = \gamma\sqrt{\beta^2-\frac 1 {n^2}}$$
though you may want to check I did that right (edit: it was wrong, I fixed it). You can also convert it into a 3 velocity with:
$$ q'_{\mu} = (\gamma', \gamma' \vec \beta') $$
or
$$ \beta' = 1-\frac{n(1-\beta^2)}{n-\beta} $$
BTW: Phase,
$$ \phi = \vec k\cdot\vec x - \omega t = k^{\mu}x_{\mu}$$
is a Lorentz invariant, so you can always transform nodes in your wave, if needed.

It would be more accurate to focus on the frequency and propagation vector of the photon relative to the electron’s frame when you mentioned the photon's four-momentum in the lab $S$.

@Adversing why? Do we ever study the meaning of $\vec k$ and $\omega$ in relativistic media?

In a relativistic context we do analyze the propagation characteristics of waves using the four-wave vector $k^\mu = (\frac{\omega}{c}, \vec{k})$ instead of considering $\vec{k}$ and $\omega$ separately because it's invariant under Lorentz transformations. Hence, it allows us to understand better wave-particle interactions when i.e. electrons move at relativistic speed in various materials.

I said in relativistic media. I'm not ready to declare a dielectric moving it 0.9 c can be treated like a dielectric at rest. If you want to derive that fact, that would be really cool: ___________ .

The electron may be at rest in your frame, but the medium with all of its charged constituents is not. They will deflect in the electrostatic field of the electron.
This is why you will see the charges around your electron radiating and not the electron itself.
